# Agisoft Metashape - inactive align chunks

Tags: point-clouds, 3d-model

I have two point clouds on which I want to build one model. 
I loaded them into various chunks, built a model for each. Then they need to be aligned using  align on chunks. But this button is inactive for me.

What have I done wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65qUv.png)

error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW4Ix.png)

Comment: Did you select both your models?

Comment: Yes. When I did it through the Batch Process, I get error (in the picture): At least two images are required for matching
Error: Not enough cameras.
So, where can i get cameras? Import cameras also inactive.
@s.k

Answer (score 0):

Chunk alignment works if you have at least a couple of aligned images in each chunk selected for the alignment.

If you do not have any aligned images and have only polygonal models in the chunks, you can try to use Align_model_to_model script from official repository:
https://github.com/agisoft-llc/metashape-scripts/blob/master/src/align_model_to_model.py